# C to MIPS translation for 2D array and bitwise operation

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

Im trying to translate the below piece of C code to MIPS, but don't know how to translate the part  `m |= c;`
what is the MIPS code for the above?

Comment: how is `grid` declared? is it `int grid[N_ROWS][N_COLS]` or maybe `double **grid`?

Comment: @tstanisl its int

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't compile it and see for yourself?

Comment: If you edit your question to be trivial and with no details or even an attempt at using the `or` instruction, expect to have it downvoted.  Especially when part of the title (2D arrays) doesn't even apply anymore.  Also not specifying where `m` is stored (in memory or a register), so an answer could just say `or $t0, $t0, $t1`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's decompose this statement:

```
m |= constant;
```

This in a category called an assignment operator, and these are expanded like this:

```
m = m | constant
^   ^
|   |
|   +--- source/read
|
+-- target/written
```

So, whereas regular assignment (`=`) only writes, these assignment operators both read and write target expression on the left-hand side.  (`col++` is also a read-modify-write operation, and can be thought of as `col += 1` as well as `col = col + 1`).  Once understood, these assignment operators are handy and succinct, and also help in that we don't have to repeat a complex expression, such as the array indexing in your example.

The `|` operator stands for [logical or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_(OR)).  In C this operator will perform the logical or operation on every single bit of the two inputs to produce an output of the same size, so for `int` of 4 bytes large, will perform 32 individual "or" operations, position by position.

"Or"ing with a constant is used to set corresponding bits — where there is a 1 in the constant, the output for that bit will be 1, and where there is a 0 in the constant, the output for that bit will be the value of the other input (at that bit position).

What this is saying is: take the current value of `m`, then OR in the constant, and write that value to become the new current value of `m`.

MIPS has an `or` instruction and and `ori` instruction.

If the variable `m` is in a register, this can be done in one instruction, assuming that the constant will fit into 16-bit immediate form (and otherwise, a programmer, in some cases the assembler, may convert that into two or three instructions, one or two extra to manifest the full constant value, then the MIPS or instruction).  That `or` instruction will both source and target the register for `m`.

However, if the variable, `m` is in memory, then, because MIPS is a load/store machine, we have to load a copy of `m` into a register, then do the `or` operation (as described above), and then store it back into memory to update the variable where it is living.

Arrays — more specifically all their elements — are necessarily in memory, so they will need this full treatment.  You already have a computation to obtain the address of the element.

---

Most would use a shift: `sll $t3, $t2, 2` to multiply by 4 as this can be cheaper on lower-end hardware.

Don't forget to initialize `row=0;` at the start, instead of relying on the simulator to have cleared the registers.

(And don't forget to increment `col++`.)

The `la` of grid can be moved to outside of and before the loop as one optimization, since the value it produces doesn't change during the loop's execution.  (This is called [loop invariant code motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion).)  If you do that, just don't clobber `$t0` in another part of the code, as long it is still needed.

There are other optimizations possible in assembly, such as doing the first multiplication (`row` times column size) in the outer loop instead of in the inner loop, since within the inner loop, the `row` variable doesn't change, and so that is a constant value for each execution of the inner loop.

Each of these code motion optimizations requires the usage of an additional CPU register (for the duration of some loop), which is one reason why MIPS and other newer processors have so many registers.

(Further optimizations are also possible by changing from array indexing to pointers, and then from re-computing the element's byte address, to maintaining that address as a variable that is live throughout the loop(s).)

Suggest sticking with `$t` registers in general, there's 10 of them so plenty for your code.  (`$s` registers are supposed to be saved & restored when used, they are used by code that makes function calls, so if the body of your loop had a function call as part of it or as part of the assignment statement, we would choose `$s` registers for `row` and `col` and anything else we want to both be in registers and survive the function call.)

Comment: *can be cheaper on lower-end hardware.* - I'd expect a shift to *always* be lower latency than an immediate `mul`, except on some special-purpose CPU designed to clock pretty slow but with a high-performance multiplier.  (e.g. some ARM Cortex-M CPUs have an option for a fast multiplier.  I forget if it's 1 cycle, but less than 3.)  Anyway, your phrasing implies that a multiply is often equal to a shift in cost, which is probably not true, especially without OoO exec to hide latency even if execution-unit availability isn't a problem for throughput.